# Regex for matching with and without quotes for dynamic JSON

Tags: json, regex

I have the following text strings:

```
"Name":"John"}]
"Age":36
"Address":"ABC,PQR234[]/.,@ANYCHARACTERS"
"Gender":null
```

I need to get two groups (key value pair) from this such that the output would be only:

```
Key|Value
Name|John
Age|36
Address|ABC,PQR234[]/.,@ANYCHARACTERS
```

The requirement is to have a single regex to grab everything in the double quotes if the double quotes are present. If not, take the value without the quotes. 
In our example above, 36 and null are the one without the quotes and they need to be captured as well.
I have tried a lot but have failed to do so.

UPDATE: 
I don't know why I am getting down votes for this question. Yes this is JSON that I am trying to parse but there is a reason behind why I am doing this and not using any document parser.
I am supposed to use Talend for getting a dynamic JSON converted into Key Value Pair. What I mean by dynamic is the fields of the JSON can vary and hence I do not have a fixed schema and hence cannot use a document parser (which demands a fixed structure of JSON). I am devising a solution to get around this using Normalizer (on comma) and then extracting the key value pair which will be in double quotes using Regular Expressions. I tried many things on my own and since I am not an expert in Regular expressions, I have come here to get inputs.
If you know any better solution to this, I would be very happy to get your inputs.

Comment: This smells like `JSON`, don't you wanna use a decent parser instead? Also, if not, what have you come up with so far and what programming language do you use?

Comment: Ok, to answer that let me tell you everything. So, I am supposed to use Talend for getting a dynamic JSON converted into Key Value Pair. What I mean by dynamic is the fields of the JSON can vary and hence I do not have a fixed schema and hence cannot use a document parser (which demands a fixed structure of JSON). I am devising a solution to get around this using Normalizer (on comma) and then extracting the key value pair which will be in double quotes using Regular Expressions. I tried many things on my own and since I am not an expert in Regular expressions, I have come here to get inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
/"?([^\n"]*)"?:"?([^\n"]*)"?/
```

Explained in detail at:

https://regex101.com/r/UM0rl2/1/

Comment: That's what I cannot understand. People without knowing the complete scenario downvote. I did not give you the downvote.